# Exception handling during database operations

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube

I am bit curious to know in the below code snippet, is there any chances of database connection not being closed. I am getting an issue in the SonarQube telling "Method may fail to close database resource"

```
   try {       
        con = OracleUtil.getConnection();
        pstmtInsert = con.prepareStatement(insertUpdateQuery);
        pstmtInsert.setString(++k, categoryCode);
        pstmtInsert.clearParameters();
        pstmtInsert = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
        for (i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
            pstmtInsert.setString(1, p_setId);
            addCount = pstmtInsert.executeUpdate();
            if (addCount == 1) {
                con.commit();
                usercount++;
            } else {
                con.rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    catch (SQLException sqle) {
        _log.error(methodName, "SQLException " + sqle.getMessage());
        sqle.printStackTrace();
        EventHandler.handle();//calling event handler
        throw new BTSLBaseException(this, "addInterfaceDetails", "error.general.sql.processing");
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        _log.error(methodName, " Exception " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        EventHandler.handle();//calling event handler
        throw new BTSLBaseException(this, "addInterfaceDetails", "error.general.processing");
    }

    finally {

        try {
            if (pstmtInsert != null) {
                pstmtInsert.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _log.errorTrace(methodName, e);
        }
        try {
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _log.errorTrace(methodName, e);
        }

        if (_log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            _log.debug("addRewardDetails", " Exiting addCount " + addCount);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this looks fairly solid to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7+, I suggest you use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). It ensures the resources are closed after the operation is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved when I closed the first prepare statement before starting the another one.

added below code snippet after the line pstmtInsert.clearParameters();

```
    try {
            if (pstmtInsert != null) {
                pstmtInsert.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _log.errorTrace(methodName, e);
        }
```